# Change with radio to checkbox and SQL with a few category

Tags: php, sql, checkbox, radio-button

I am looking for idea to change radio to checkbox and make SQL SELECT with it:

Now The user chooses category by form radio (one category) code:

```
$zapytanie = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM pytania_new WHERE Kategoria = :kategoria');
```

and the script show all questions with one category which we chose.

Now I would like to have choosing a few category, so I changed my current code to show checkbox form and save chosen category to array, but now I don't know how to do SQL which show me questions with a few category

```
$zapytanie = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM pytania_new WHERE Kategoria = :kategoria AND :kategoria2');
```

this doesn't want to work.

and the next problem is how to check how much category SQL should download from database.

I hope that you help me with it :)

Answer (score 0):

`AND` operator requires column to be mentioned, not value
So in your case `Kategoria = :kategoria AND Kategoria2 = :kategoria2`

But we don't have your structure, maybe you don't have second column, so you need to recieve 2 rows as a result? Then use `OR` operator:

`Kategoria = :kategoria OR Kategoria = :kategoria2`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple for loop.

```
$categories = array("first","second");
$query = "";
$delimiter = "";
foreach($categories as $category) {
  $query .= $delimiter . "kategoria = $category";
  $delimiter = " OR "; //Dont really know how your sql looks but this makes more sense. Otherwise change to AND if a row can have multiple categories
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pytania_new WHERE $query";
```

Comment: I don't want to use OR

I have just found this:

    SELECT * FROM pytania WHERE Kategoria IN ("UTK","Pro")
And in phpMyAdmin it works :)

But in POD not 

tried this:

        $licz = $pdo->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pytania_new WHERE Kategoria IN (:kategorie)');//policzenie wedlug kategorii zdefiniowanej w 'bindValue'
    $licz -> bindValue(':kategorie', $kategories, PDO::PARAM_STR); //przypisanie wartosci $kategoria dla 'bindValue'
    $licz -> execute();
but it didn't work :/

I think that problem's in BindValue, because it's array,not STR,do you know something other parametrs for array?

Comment: OK I found solving this query: $licz = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pytania_new WHERE Kategoria IN ('$kategories')");
but when I tried choose 2 category, the query look like this: PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pytania_new WHERE Kategoria IN ('UTK,Pro') ) 0
their is error ('UTK,Pro'), because it should be ('UTK','Pro'), I tried to changed this, but it doesn;t work :/ any suggestion?

Comment: OK I did it :) I will write tomorrow how I did it, because now I cannot do answer

Answer (score 0):

OK, so on the first we have to create string with all categories like this:

```
$kategorie = join(',',$kategoria);
```

After that there is simple SQL which can find a few category in base

```
$zapytanie = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM pytania_new WHERE Kategoria IN ($kategories)");
```

and it is all :)